# Laravel's validator passes for empty string with 'nullable' rule

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

Example:

```
Validator::make(['x' => ''], ['x' => 'nullable|integer|min:1'])->errors()->all();
```

Output:

```
[]
```

When `x` is null or 1,2,3, etc. it works fine.

When `x` is something else except empty string validator says about errors.

Column in database can be NULL or positive integer so when I pass empty string, validator tells me that it's fine, but mysql throws exception because it tries to save `''` (empty string) in nullable integer column.

Only allowed values for field are: `null`, `1,2,3,4,...`, everything else should fail.

If I add `required` rule then validator fails for `null` value ('nullable|required|integer|min:1')

Comment: Rule `nullable` only says, that value can be `null`, but it does not convert empty value to `null` itself.

Comment: The value is not null so `nullable` is not really in effect here. If you do `Validator::make(['x' => ''], ['x' => 'integer|min:1'])->errors()->all();` you still get no errors

Answer (score 1):

Laravel 5.4 comes with a global middleware to convert all empty strings to null by default. If you don't want this then comment out the middleware from the list.

app/Http/Kernel.php

```
\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading through the source code there's this function (in `Validator.php`)

```
protected function isValidatable($rule, $attribute, $value)
{
    return $this->presentOrRuleIsImplicit($rule, $attribute, $value) &&
           $this->passesOptionalCheck($attribute) &&
           $this->isNotNullIfMarkedAsNullable($attribute, $value) &&
           $this->hasNotFailedPreviousRuleIfPresenceRule($rule, $attribute);
}

 protected function presentOrRuleIsImplicit($rule, $attribute, $value)
 {
    if (is_string($value) && trim($value) === '') {
        return $this->isImplicit($rule);
    }

    return $this->validatePresent($attribute, $value) || $this->isImplicit($rule);
}
```

The function `presentOrRuleIsImplicit` basically says that if the value is `''` then only validate it if the rule is "implicit" (basically if the attribute is required).

In that case if it is both required and nullable validation would fail because `''` is not the same as null.

Laravel 5.4 has a built-in middleware called `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` which basically helps deal with this discrepancy by taking all `''` values and converting them to null.